# Powerhsell/Unix Bash - Find missing numbers for a set of files

Tags: powershell

I'm currently trying to detect some missing files for batches.

This batch generates files with following convention:

- File_1_01.txt (first hour, first iteration)
- File_1_02.txt

I want to create a script to find out which iteration is missing.
I found this piece of code in powershell

```
function missingNumbers {
Get-ChildItem -path ./* -include *.txt 
| Where{$_.Name -match '\d+'} 
| ForEach{$Matches[0]} 
| sort {[int]$_} |% {$i = 1}
{while ($i -lt $_){$i;$i++};$i++}}
```

However when i use this script against

```
 File_1_01.txt
 File_1_02.txt
 File_1_04.txt
```

It doesn't return entry 03

**Investigations**
Remove hourly occurrence File_<**1**>_helps and script behaves as expected.

If i concatenate hour and occurrence, script will display all numbers before 101.

I'm open to having sth in Unix as well.

I had another approach in mind, removing the common text between all files but have no idea how to do it.

Comment: `$var = Get-ChildItem -path ./* -include *.txt; for($i=0;$i -lt <how many iterations>; $i++){for($j=0;$j -lt <how many hours>; $j++){try {Test-Path "File_$i_$j.txt" -PathType leaf}catch{Echo "File_$i_$j.txt is missing"}}}` This might work...

Comment: Thanks Neko, will give it a try tomorrow. Can Powershell find the lower string shared across the file? Here, that would be File_ but in other folders it could be ExtractBatch1x01 etc... Can Powershell do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of matching the 1 every time, you can match the 2 digits `\d\d` at the end.  Putting the pipe symbol on the next line like that will only work in powershell 7.

```
Get-ChildItem -path ./* -include *.txt |
  Where Name -match \d\d |
  ForEach{ $Matches[0] } |
  sort {[int]$_} |
  % { $i = 1 } { while ($i -lt $_){ $i;$i++ }; $i++ }


3
```

You could put all the numbers together like this, but then they'd have to all be right after each other.  Adjust the match pattern or get-childitem for your needs.

```
Get-ChildItem -path ./* -include *.txt |
  Where Name -match '(\d).(\d\d)' |
  ForEach{ $Matches[1] + $Matches[2] }

101
102
104
```

Comment: Thanks ! Noticed it works when we keep same hourly (File_1_). When we have File_2_ for instance, script doesn't word as expected.
-------------------
File_2_03.txt
File_2_04.txt
File_1_04.txt
File_1_01.txt
File_1_02.txt 
-----------------



Nothing returned